# Deploy to solution into Sharepoint 2013 GAC

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint

I have a problem that a feature needs log4net, but can't find the assembly.

I created a solution (.wsp) to deploy the third-party library log4net. I deployed the wsp into my sharepoint via commandline and added the log4net to the GAC.

If I turn on a installed feature the feature is missing the following assembly:

`"log4net, Version=1.2.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a"`

When I take a look into C:/Windows/assembly the correct log4net version is displayed there.

I have two different folders C:\Windows\assembly and C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly which both contain assemblys. Which folder is used by Sharepoint 2013?

Did I something wrong? I used the following commands:

```
Add-SPSolution -LiteralPath C:\sharepoint\log4net.wsp
Install-SPSolution -Identity log4net.wsp -GACDeployment
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Before you enabled a feature you have to open a new instance of the sharepoint commandline.

Answer (score 0):

Your assembly should be here in SharePoint 2013 :
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL

Do you locate log4net ?